# Automate build SQL database projects through VS-CMD, other options?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2012, jenkins-pipeline, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to automate build process for SSDT SQL Database Project.
I have a build script that i can run on VS command prompt to get dacpac file however my window agent doesn't have VS command prompt so i'm looking for other options here.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

use "Visual studio build" task which will automatically generate dacpac file for you for your database project.

If you pass the solution path to VS build task, it will take all the deployable project inside the solution and creates the necessary artifacts in a separate zip for each deployable project in a solution.

Reference: https://www.gatevnotes.com/continuous-integration-continuous-deployment-of-ssdt-projects-creating-azure-devops-pipelines/

Comment: I tried to do that thru Jenkins and it didn't seem to outwork.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Command Line task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to run a program from the command prompt. Azure Pipelines puts your inline script contents into a temporary batch file (.cmd) in order to run it. When you want to run a batch file from another batch file in Windows CMD, you must use the `call` command:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#running-batch-and-cmd-files

For example :

`echo call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"`

Comment: Problem is windows agent doesn't have VSDEVCMD so i don't think regular windows cmd would execute the build script. I use Jenkins automation tool FYI. I wish it was Azure pipeline much easier.

Comment: Do you use Self-hosted agent? Do you mean you didn't install VS on the agent machine?

Comment: Yes, anyway to get only VSDEVCMD out there without installing anything else?

Comment: No, you have to install VS on the agent machine. You may consider installing VS community version on your agent machine to use VsDevCmd.bat file.